# Can't fade color to Black p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have been working on a wallpaper of a flow field lately.
The flow field is generated using Perlin noise and written in p5.js.

Here is my code:

```js
let particles = [];
let num = 1000;
let noiseScale = 0.005;
let _alpha = 1;
let seed = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    colorMode(HSB);
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        particles.push(createVector(random(width), random(height)));
    }
    strokeWeight(1);
    background(0);
}

function draw() {
    noiseSeed(seed);
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        let particle = particles[i];

        let _noise = noise(particle.x * noiseScale, particle.y * noiseScale);
        let angle = TWO_PI * _noise;

        particle.x += cos(angle);
        particle.y += sin(angle);

        let hue = map(particle.x, 0, width, 0, 360);

        stroke(hue, 100, 100, _alpha);
        point(particle.x, particle.y);

        if (!outScreen(particle)) {
            particle.x = random(width);
            particle.y = random(height);
        }
    }
    background(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

function outScreen(vec) {
    return vec.x >= 0 && vec.x <= width && vec.y >= 0 && vec.y <= height;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height: 100%">
<main></main>
```

Every frame the dots are drawn on the screen. To prevent the screen from becoming too full, a box the size of the screen is then painted. This box is black and has a low alpha value, to darken the screen. However, if the lines are too dark, they won't become completely black.

After about 2 minutes you can see a rainbow in the background. But this shouldn't be visible at all due to the darkening.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIu3L.png)

I tried to paint the points with a weaker color using the alpha value, but this didn't change anything.